# How to display if you signed out in PHP?

Tags: php, authentication, logout

So I have this index.php file and another levels.php file where the logged users can choose levels. If I want to log out from the session I want it to bring the user back to index.php, but since logging out sends no POST data, I can't tell the index.php that the user just logged out.

How could I manage it, so that a little div would inform the user that he has just logged out succesfully?

Comment: Are you using php sessions? Are you using a database? Are you only using cookies? You have a lack of information here for us to help you.

Comment: yup, sessions, I store the users in databases (of course), and no, I'm not using cookies! :D When the logout button is pressed, it redirects to logout.php which only unsets the $_SESSION['username'] then redirects to index.php WHERE I want the "successful logout" div.

Comment: I think your question would benefit from some code snippets. So answers do not have to guess at what you are doing. But it may just be as simple as setting `$_SESSION['just_logged_out']=true`, and upon entering index.php, you look for that... and `unset($_SESSION['just_logged_out'])` once you have displayed the message.

Comment: If you're using `$_SESSION` you're most likely using cookies. Otherwise how are you passing the session token along to the server with every request? If you're only doing it through POST requests in the HTTP headers then you've definitely painted yourself into a corner where you need to rely on every request to be a POST request. You can unpaint this by passing the token along as part of the query string, for example, but then why not just rely on cookies and make your life easier?

Comment: But at logging out the session ends, so I cannot check whether the just_logged_out is true or false. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You are indeed wrong. If the stateful information stored in `$_SESSION` is not present then they are definitely not logged in.

Comment: You said you only unset `$_SESSION['username']`. So that suggests to me, that sessions are still existing. Anyhow, I generally just create a timed message from the logout.php showing "Logging out...", which then bounces back to home once the timer is up. People have never mentioned confusion from the process.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of being signed in (typically associated with the retention of state between the client and server) is addressed most commonly through the use of cookies (or more aptly [sessions](http://php.net/book.session)). This has nothing to do with sending POST requests to the server. Just checking that the stateful information is still valid.

Assuming you do something similar to this to sign the user in...

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($user->signIn()) { // successful sign in attempt
    $_SESSION['signedIn'] = true;
    $_SESSION['userId'] = $user->id;
} else {
    // failed to sign in
}
```

Assuming you do this to sign the user out...

```
<?php
session_start();

// Destroy the session cookie on the client
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Destroy the session data on the server
session_destroy();
```

Then determining whether or not the user is signed in from index.php should be as simple as this...

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION['signedIn'])) { // They are signed in
    /* Do stuff here for signed in user */
} else { // They are not
    /* Do other stuff here for signed out user */
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this that all the users that just came from somewhere else and are not signed in are going to see "succesfully signed out". Thats why I want that IF the user signs out he can see the sign out message. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No they wouldn't. All users that came from somewhere else would never have passed the sign in validation routine.

Comment: The idea that you want to say "successfully signed out" in index.php, on a request statelessly associated with a previous action, may be what's tripping you up here. Instead, adjust your thinking to how HTTP actually works. The user sends over a request to sign out. That request is captured by the server. The response of "you're signed out successfully" should come from that particular request. Not a completely separate request to index.php that has no associated state. Trying to do it any other way would likely be an exercise in futility. Why use HTTP just to break how HTTP works?